# printer epson L380 not working in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: printing

Ubuntu 20.04 automatically detected the printer and installed the drivers but printer printing blank pages.Can anyone help me to resolve.
I tried to install the drivers but installation is not allowed .[image]

Comment: _...but installation is not allowed._  Please click [edit] and tell us what command(s) you used to try the install, and the failure message(s).

Answer (score 0):

You downloaded a wrong driver. Ubuntu 20.04 has only 64-bit version, but you downloaded a 32-bit driver.

You need an `amd64` deb file.

Comment: "dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem." i am getting above message while trying with 64 bit driver.Can any one share epson380 printer downloading link

Comment: So run `sudo dpkg  --configure -a`

Answer (score 0):

You can download model specific drivers from Epson here,
http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/?OSC=LX
Go to the link enter your model no. and install printer as well as scanner drivers.
Also I would recommend you to install these packages using g-debi

Answer (score 0):

I just installed 20.04 I can't get my Epson L-350 printer scanner going!

It's like the bad old days of early Linux!!

My printer is like the L-200, but that driver is not in the list of Epson drivers.

I tried several different drivers, didn't work, deleted the printer, tried another driver, but I still haven't managed to print a test page!!

My old laptop runs 18.04, the printer and scanner work fine. I installed that with the download from Epson. I should have kept that .deb file!!

I also have an Epson DS-510 batch scanner, works fine in 18.04!

Is it possible to get the PPD file directly for the printer??